# Borel-measurability

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as:

$\displaystyle f(x) = \begin{cases}
 1 & \text{if $x \geq 0$} \\ 
 -1 & \text{if $x< 0$}
 \end{cases}$

I have concluded that the function $f$ is measurable since it it (piecewise) continuous. But is it Borel-measurable?

Here are my thoughts:

The function is Borel-measurable. 
Take any set $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. any open, closed or half-open interval since $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by any of these. Then $f^{-1}(A)= \emptyset \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ for every $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For  any set $B$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(B)$ is $[0,\infty), (-\infty,0),\emptyset$ or $\mathbb R$ and these four sets are Borel sets.

[ Just consider the cases $(1 \in B, -1\notin B)$, $(-1 \in B, 1\notin B)$, $(1 \notin B, -1\notin B)$ and $(1 \in B, -1\in B)$].

This is in fact a simple function: $f=I_{[0,\infty)}-I_{(-\infty,0)}$

Comment: For clarity, if I choose an $A$ where $1,-1\notin A$ then $f^{-1}(A)=\emptyset$. If I choose an $A$ where $1\in A$ then $f^{-1}(A)= [0,\infty)$ and if I choose an $A$ where $-1\in A$ then $f^{-1}(A)=(-\infty,0)$. I think this is correctly understood. The option with $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of the last two intervals. Right?

Comment: Allow me to correct myself. If I choose an $A$ where $1,-1 \in A$ then $f^{-1}(A)=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @saleem Yes, you have got the  argument right.